# Variable outside of callback in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I am fairly new to NodeJS and to JavaScript in general. Here is my script:

```
var data = [];

    client.query(

      'SELECT * FROM cds',
      function selectCb(err, results, fields) {

        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        console.log(results);
        console.log(fields);

        data.push(results);
      }
    );

    console.log(data);
```

How can I get access to the `results` (or `data`) var outside of the callback? I don't want to have to write a ton of callbacks inside of each other when running queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. The point of those callbacks is that the rest of the code can execute and does not have to wait for the query. So assuming `results` is an element of `data` in your last line does not make much sense, because the query hasn't completed yet.

Comment: I figured my design was wrong and was hoping for a better solution. Do you know how I can get data from the query using node-mysql with out using a callback?

Comment: It sounds like you want synchronous code, so that the function waits for the query to be ended. I'm not sure that's the best approach. Is there any reason you don't just execute query's dependencies inside the callback?

Comment: Well there may be 2-3 queries I will write all the time in the beginning of my app. I don't want to get deep nested into callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is synchronous (or blocking) execution, and that's really contrary to the design and spirit of node.js.

Node, like JavaScript, is single-threaded. If you have blocking code, then *the whole process is stopped*.

This means you have to use callbacks for anything that will take a long time (like querying from a database).  If you're writing a command-line tool that runs through in one pass, you may be willing to live with the blocking.  But if you're writing any kind of responsive application (like a web site), then blocking is murder.

So it's *possible* that someone could give you an answer on how to make this a blocking, synchronous call.  If so, and if you implement it, you're doing it wrong.  You may as well use a multi-threaded scripting language like Ruby or Python.

Writing callbacks isn't so bad, but it requires some thought about architecture and packaging in ways that are probably unfamiliar for people unaccustomed to the style.

Comment: I come from a PHP background thats probably why I am confused. It looks like I need to rethink how I build applications when using NodeJS. Thank you

Comment: nodeJS is a different paradigm, do not try to code it like synchronous systems, the callbacks is what allows is to run as fast as it does (non-blocking). It's a bit harder in the beginning, but it's still a lot easier than trying to implement asynchronous code in languages like C, Java or PHP

Answer (score 1):

Node.js uses the [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) for all of it's asynchronous interfaces.  There is a *lot* of discussion around this and [modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow) that have been created for easing the pain of nested callbacks.  There were rumors for awhile that node.js might start reintroducing Promises into it's core in the v0.7.x branch, but I'm not sure if that's true or not.

Short of using one of the flow-control libraries from the link above (or rolling your own), you're either going to have to live with the nested callbacks, or simply provide a function reference for the callback.  E.g.,

```
var data = [],
    handler = function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        ...
    };
client.query('SELECT * FROM cds', handler);
```